# Training a network to identify X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 <= 25

Tags: python, machine-learning, 3d, neural-network, pybrain

I'm trying to get a Neural Network to predict whether or not a point falls on or within the sphere formed by the equation X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 <= 25. I'm doing this using Pybrain and python, however, no matter how I configure the thing, I can't get an accuracy well above 10%. 9 times out of 10, the network will converge on an error about .06, .07, and refuse to continue training... If anyone can shed some light on the situation that'd be great!

If faced with this problem, how many hidden nodes would you use? Tanh or sigmoid? Learning rate? Momentum? P.S. I do have some experience with Neural Nets, I coded one for tic-tac-toe in java from scratch, and wanted to learn how to use Pybrain better and I figured this would be a good project! (3 dimensions, infinite data, clear cut)

Could this just be a pybrain problem? Should I try another set-up? If so, any recommendations?

Code below if you want to give it a shot - every variable can be determined upon execution, so you can mess around (except tanh/sigmoid - if you want to try sigmoid, just remove the hiddenclass=Tanhlayer argument in net's declaration, it will default)

```
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
from pybrain.datasets import SupervisedDataSet
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer
from pybrain.structure import TanhLayer
from random import randint
import random

def getAnswer(decimal):
    answer = -1
    if decimal >= 0:
        answer = 1

    return answer

nodes = int(input("node number: "))
bias = bool(input("Bias: "))
net = buildNetwork(3, nodes, 1, hiddenclass=TanhLayer, bias=bias)
net.randomize()

#Generate Dataset
ds = SupervisedDataSet(3, 1)
dataSize = int(input("Sample size: "))

#Randomly generate points for the data set
randRate = int(input("Cluter probability: "))
for i in range(0, dataSize):
    randX = randint(-6, 6)
    randY = randint(-6, 6)
    randZ = randint(-6, 6)
    target = -1

    if(randX**2 + randY**2 + randZ**2) <= 25:
        target = 1

    if (random.random() < randRate) and target == 1:  #Clutter the data
        target = -1

    #print("Adding ", randX, ", ", randY, ", ", randZ, " - target: ", target)
    ds.addSample([randX, randY, randZ], [target, ])

#Train the model using the user specified input
ls = float(input('Enter learning speed:'))
mom = float(input('Enter momentum: '))
epochs = input('Enter training amount (Enter "con" to go until Convergence"): ')
dispRate = int(input('Enter display rate: '))

trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, ds, ls, mom)
if epochs != 'con':
    epochs = int(epochs)
    for i in range(0, epochs):
        error = trainer.train()
        if(i % dispRate == 0):
            print("Training is ", (i/epochs) * 100, "% Complete. Error = ", error)
else:
    trainer.trainUntilConvergence(ds, verbose=True)

print("Testing accuracy...") #Test the accuracy with 1000 random test points
correct = 0
for n in range(0, 1000):
    randX = randint(-6, 6)
    randY = randint(-6, 6)
    randZ = randint(-6, 6)
    answer = getAnswer(net.activate([randX, randY, randZ]))
    inSphere = randX**2 + randY**2 + randZ**2 <= 25
    if(answer == 1) and inSphere == True:
        correct += 1
    elif(answer == -1) and inSphere == False:
        correct += 1
print("Accuracy: ", 100 * (correct/1000), "%")

inp = ''
#Let the user test the model
while inp != 'quit':
    tX = input('sample X: ')
    tY = input('sample Y: ')
    tZ = input('sample Z: ')
    print(net.activate([tX, tY, tZ]))
    inp = input("keep going? (quit to stop)")
```

Comment: Since this is just a binary classifier, have you tried flipping the signs of your output? You'd be getting around 94% accuracy, right?

Comment: The idea of the project was to understand PyBrain better, and although that works, that really didn't help! Bonus points for creativity!